# how to get ng-model value of text box in controller

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type='text' ng-model='courseIDER' ng-change="india()" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter CourseId">`{{courseIDER}}`<br>
```

suppose there is a text box where one can input value and i will be getting what one enters by `{{courseIDER}}`. But my problem is i want this value in controller.

As an angularjs newbie i'm hoping anyone helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: share more code please

Comment: you could use `$scope.courseIDER` inside your controller

Comment: I am bit confused by OP's question with the keyword `controller.As`

Comment: im getting $scope.courseIDER as undefined

Comment: Share the entire html defined for that controller, it might be that you have several scopes (inner scopes)

Comment: Sry its just controller, thats the end of line

Comment: thats a huge html page. It would be confusing ...

Comment: @sandeepvarmapenmetsa please create a fiddle or plunker then

Comment: we are interested only in the part from where ng-controller starts and where it ends. The issue might be particular because it is huge and has inner scopes.

Comment: i got it by using ng-model =''courseIDER.selected''... Thanks guys

Comment: whatever `courseIDER.selected` is, you didn't mention it at all in the question, so the comment suggesting that your problem is resolved doesn't really make sense.  Honestly, it's not really clear at all what the problem was in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Define courseIDER as a $scope obj in your controller

```
function controller($scope, ... other injections) {
  $scope.courseIDER;
}
```

now, when the input changes, so will $scope.courseIDER.

you can now use the courseIDER in any function / object/ array you want